Audio object in JS not working across website
I have an audio element, which plays along with my alert box that shows up when a certain action happens. all of the pages on my website share the same JS file, and my JS file is in assets/js/core.js, and my audio file is in assets/audio/error.mp3. The audio only seems to play in index page, which is in the root directory of my website. all of the other pages are in /company/... and company/legal/... and so on. (the ... represent the files that are in the directories.) I know that the page must first fetch the audio file, and the file path for each page would be different, so the JS would have to point to multiple directories.
This is the original JS code I had, which only plays in the index file:
// Create an audio element
    let audio = new Audio("assets/audio/error.mp3");
    audio.play(); // Play the audio

and an alternative I had tried to ake the audio play in all pages:
// Create an audio element
    let audio = new Audio("assets/audio/error.mp3", "../audio/error.mp3", "../../assets/audio/error.mp3");
    audio.play(); // Play the audio


You need to specify the absolute URL of the audio file so that it always points to the same unique resource and thus works properly on every page, eg. :
const loc = window.location;
const url = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + '/assets/audio/error.mp3';
const audio = new Audio(url);


Do i just replace what I have with this? or do I add this onto the current code I currrently have?

I currenly have my code set up as this. However its not working. const loc = window.location;  const url = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname + "/assets/audio/error.mp3";  const error = new Audio(url);  error.play();

i ran this code inside the console of the web browser. it gave me this error: GET http://127.0.0.1/assets/audio/error.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

That is an example, you mentioned "_the audio only seems to play in index page, which is in the root directory of my website. _", and since the relative URL "assets/audio/error.mp3" works on that index page, I assumed constructing the url by appending the relative URL to the website hostname would work. But I can't guess whether there is or what could be the path that points to the "root directory" if you don't specify it in the first place. The answer remains the same : you need to specify the absoute url.

Another example, let say your index page is loaded from http://127.0.0.1/src/index.html, here the relative path from the root to index.html is "/src" so in this case you would replace /assets/audio/error.mp3 by /src/assets/audio/error.mp3 in the code.

Im using liveserver in vs code, and it does seem its there, it just keeps refusing to connect to it. im thinking its because its a local server

The live preview server works on a specific port, and I just realized you need to use host instead of hostname (which doesn't include de port, if any). See revised answer.
